# Expand the first row initially using MVC + Server Binding

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Hierarchical grid that is bound to the server and is in MVC  (.DataSource(d => d.Server()))

When the grid first loads I'd like the grid to expand the first row by default so the detail view is showing.

Can this be done without Javascript (preferred) or in Javascript if needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

**Script**

```
 function _GridItemDataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
    }
```

**View**

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<TwoModelInSinglePageModel.SampleModel>()
    .Name("grid12")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.studentclass).HeaderTemplate("<input id='selectall' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox'  />").ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox_#=inx#' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />");
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleDescription);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleCode);
        columns.Bound(p => p.SampleItems);
    })
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("client-template")
        .AutoBind(true)
             .Events(events => events.DataBound("_GridItemDataBound"))
       .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
            .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "Test"))
     )
  )
```